# Django: sending email x days later

Tags: django, cron

In my Django project, users are allowed to register to a free trial, but if they do not complete a purchase within 15 days, their accounts are locked out until they do complete the purchase. After 13 days (ie within 48 hours or expiry) I wish to send an email the registered user reminding him/her to purchase.

Currently, I have a cron job set up to run daily and check all trial accounts if the registration date and current date are 2 days apart and if so, I send an email.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to do this?

Comment: Why is this not elegant?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty standard way to do it to me.

Comment: +1 to both other comments. Unless you have need for more advanced tasks, a cronjob sounds like the most elegant solution.

Comment: haha This is my first web server project and dealing with things like these so I just wasn't sure if this was the correct approach. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: If you are open to a 3rd-party solution, use https://www.intercom.io. It lets you send automatic emails based on when different user criteria.

Comment: I agree that cron is a good solution.  Here is a nice django package that can make cron easier (you only need one cron job and then can create an unlimited number of django jobs to run): https://github.com/andybak/django-cron

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with your cron file you should check out [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/), an asynchronous task queue written in Python. It was originally created with Django in mind but has since been broken out [into a separate package](https://github.com/ask/django-celery). What you want to do then is set up a [Celerybeat schedule](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "purchase-reminder": {
        "task": "accounts.tasks.remind",
        "schedule": timedelta(hours=24),
    },
}
```

This will call the task (read: function) `accounts.tasks.remind` every 24 hours.